# rails tries to destroy from non existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, destroy

I have a problem with simple delete action.

I have a view

```
%p
  Name:
  = @element.name
%p
  Description:
  = @element.description
%p
  = link_to 'edit', edit_element_path(@element)
  |
  = link_to 'delete', @element, :confirm => 'Are you shure?', :method => :delete
```

When I try to click on that delete in browser and clik OK it says that it can not delete from unexisting table elements_muscle_groups, why does he tries to delete from that unexisting table anyway?

By the way I am using Rails 4

You can see the controller code on screenshot.

Sorry for eng and ty for help.

[image]

EDIT:
Hi I have one more thing to add,

Element
`has_and_belongs_to_many :muscle_groups`

MuscleGroup
`has_and_belongs_to_many :elements`

so maybe it should delete from elements_muscle_groups, but why does that table does not exist then?

Comment: you need to run a migration for creating join table as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from rails api:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many

> has_and_belnogs_to_many: Specifies a many-to-many relationship with another class. This associates two classes via an intermediate join table. Unless the join table is explicitly specified as an option, it is guessed using the lexical order of the class names. So a join between Developer and Project will give the default join table name of “developers_projects” because “D” outranks “P”.

so you need to make sure you have a table called

`elements_muscle_groups` with `element_id: integer` and `muscle_group_id:integer`

Comment: looks like it did, do you have the same problem and you can't solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use Rails 4 much, But I think you are trying to achieve it wrongly:
your destroy methods should look like this :-

```
def destroy 
 @element = Element.find(params[:id])
 if @element.destroy
   flash[:message] = "Record destroy successfully."
   redirect_to elements_path
 else
   flash[:error] = "Record destroy successfully."
   render element_path(@element)
 end
end
```

You could change the method accordingly. Hope it will help.

Comment: Than there must be a problem with your routes. you might not defined routes properly.

Answer (score 0):

Migration file will be look like this,

```
class CreateElementsMuscleGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :elements_muscle_groups do |t|
      t.integer  :element_id
      t.integer  :muscle_group_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Run this migration.. That will solve the issue..